# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

**I am trying to deploy my project to vercel.com**
and i got this error with 3 pages don't have any errors inside

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/applications". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at P (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:66480)
    at l (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:61660)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62861
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62834
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62654)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62918
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at l (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62611)
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at P (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:66480)
    at l (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:61660)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62861
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62834
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62654)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62918
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at l (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/686.js:10:62611)
```

i just need help to fix this

the pages contains 2 components

```
<DashboardHeader />
<ComponentName /> // Depends on page
```

every component of the three pages has a array.map in the page to show data from array to page

Comment: How can we fix it without details of your implementation? Did the link in the error have any details that would help?

Comment: I Updated the question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          {jobs.map(job => (
            <JobCard
              key={job.id}
              job={job}
              isSelected={job.id === selectedJobId}
              onSelect={handleSelectJob}
            />
          ))}
```

Removing the above code removed the issue, so that's where it comes from.
I don't know why the map is problematic on vercel with static data.